# Console window gets bugged if I get the window handle too early..?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, console-application

I'm making a console application that has to be borderless; to accomplish this, I've changed the console window styles, and the window region, as you can see below.
At some point I ran into a problem that made the console window appear usually about 2x1 characters in size, or sometimes completely bugged (invisible clientarea, some parts white, some parts transparent, random borders, etc.)
Someone told me that adding `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);` to the line where it's at right now would fix the problem. It did.
Now I'm trying to figure out why the problem existed in the first place, and if there's some other way to prevent it?

I was told that the problem might happen because Windows is trying to access the window properties (position, style, size, etc) at the same time as my program. I don't know if this is true, though.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    HANDLE hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    SMALL_RECT srWnd = {0, 0, 1, 1};
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hCon, 1, &srWnd);
    COORD cBuffSize = {81, 26};
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hCon, cBuffSize);
    srWnd.Top = 0;
    srWnd.Right = 80;
    srWnd.Bottom = 25;
    srWnd.Left = 0;
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hCon, 1, &srWnd);

    // When the next two lines are moved so that they are the first two lines inside main(), the window gets bugged.
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // Or if you just remove this line

    RECT rClnt;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rClnt);

    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP);
    LONG exStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    exStyle &= ~(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
    SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

    rClnt.right += 1;
    HRGN rgnClnt = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClnt);
    SetWindowRgn(hWnd, rgnClnt, 1);

    RECT rScrn;
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rScrn);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, rScrn.right / 2 - rClnt.right / 2, rScrn.bottom / 2 - rClnt.bottom / 2, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example for Windows 8. But you need to refresh window region each time console is moved/resized/restored.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>

//#pragma comment(lib, "uxtheme.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY policy = DWMNCRP_DISABLED;
    DwmSetWindowAttribute(hWnd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, &policy, sizeof(DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY));
    //SetThemeAppProperties(0);
    //SetWindowThemeNonClientAttributes(hWnd, STAP_VALIDBITS, 0);
    //SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    //RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
    RECT rClnt, rWnd;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rClnt);
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rWnd);
    POINT pt = {0,0};
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, &pt, 1);
    OffsetRect(&rClnt, pt.x-rWnd.left, pt.y-rWnd.top);
    HRGN rgnClnt = CreateRectRgnIndirect(&rClnt);
    SetWindowRgn(hWnd, rgnClnt, 1);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```